# rigidbody OnTriggerEnter giving me an error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, i'm trying to do infinite jumper but for some reason at `OnTriggerEnter2D` function `rb2D` gives me an error, even tho I did everything for it to work (At least I think so, because every time I do it like that it works.) Where is the mistake or am I missing something in the code?

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

Rigidbody2D rb2D;

void Start()
{
    rb2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update()
{

}
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    other.rb2D.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    other.rb2D.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpHeight, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```

Comment: Error: Type `UnityEngine.Collider2D` does not contain a definition for `rb2D` and no extension method `rb2D` of type `UnityEngine.Collider2D` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be because your `other` doesn't have a rb2D component on it, only your game object that this script is attached on.

`other` is a `Collider2D` type, which does ***not*** contain ***your*** rigidbody definition `rb2d`

I believe your code should be:

```
other.velocity = Vector2.zero;
other.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpHeight, ForceMode2D.Impulse);`
```

Note - I don't think `velocity` is part of `Collider2D` either - check out the docs [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.html).

Comment: its not that it doesnt have one on it (we actually dont know), its just the reference is to a Collider instance, not the PlayerMovement which contains the rb2D field. but in general the above answer is correct.

Comment: I realised that when I answered, I've edited my answer :-)

Comment: i just realized you might want to change your answer, as Collider doesnt know about velocity. you need to grab the rigidbody first.

Comment: @Tadas grab the rigidbody component of other -> rigidbody2d = other.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); and keep working on this

Comment: @yes That works, but still not getting why I got that error earlier.

Comment: @Tadas well the function gets a collider component, but a collider is no rigidbody and doesnt know about velocities. the original error was because you expected collider (a default unity class) to have a field called rb2D which it doesnt have (thats also what the error says). the field you expected it to have is on the class/component you created yourself, called PlayerMovement. Did that clear it up? If not, keep asking im bored atm anyway ^^